# Issues using for loops in a C++ program tasked with finding the average of each of 6 specific lines containing 25 numeric values in an XML file

Tags: c++, regex, xml

I am writing a program in C++ that is supposed to locate [6 specific lines in an XML file, each line individually holding 25 numeric values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijYWZ.png), and then find the average of those 25 numeric values for each line separately and output that average to the console window and to an output file. Additionally, I am supposed to extract the 6 time-stamps associated with those 6 specific lines. So far I have been able to implement regex to find and extract and output the 6 time-stamps with success. However, the function to find the average of the 25 numerical wattage/voltage values in each of the 6 lines outputs nothing, despite there being no compiler errors. I've tried to rubber ducky debug my code to no avail, and was hoping that a fresh pair of eyes could point out what I'm doing wrong.

**Expected output:**

2014-07-08T18:14:17.716Z

2014-07-08T18:14:18.716Z

2014-07-08T18:14:19.716Z

2014-07-08T18:14:20.716Z

2014-07-08T18:14:21.716Z

2014-07-08T18:14:22.716Z

Average Voltage: 3924.76

Average Voltage: 5793.68

Average Voltage: 7149.2

Average Wattage: 19425.5

Average Wattage: 8799.4

Average Wattage: 12602.9

**Current Output:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/44HbM.jpg

XML file: http://pastebin.com/5hMy9RzK

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
void timestamps();
void voltAvg();
using namespace std;
float sum; //global variable
ifstream infile;
ofstream outFile;

int main(){
outFile.open("Outputdata.txt");
infile.open("Groupproject.xml"); // Opens the XML file containing the information that is to be read
if (infile.fail())
{
    cout << "The file is not able to be located" << endl;
    system("Pause");
    exit(1);
}
timestamps();
voltAvg();
infile.close();
outFile.close();
system("pause");
return 0;
}


void timestamps() {
string fileinput;

regex time_regex("\\d\\d\\d\\d-\\d\\d-\\d\\d\\w\\d\\d:\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\.716Z");
smatch time_matches;



while (!infile.eof()) {  //Until the end of the file is reached, obtain each line
    getline(infile, fileinput);

    if (regex_search(fileinput, time_matches, time_regex)) { // if regex_search is able to locate a line which has elements matching the regex expression "time_regex" output the located element

        cout << "Timestamp: " << time_matches[0] << endl;
        outFile << "Timestamp: " << time_matches[0] << endl;
}

}

}

void voltAvg() {
float ave;
float dataValues;
int index;
string s;
string locateWord;

getline(infile, s); //gets first line of file
index = s.find(' '); //finds first white space
locateWord = s.substr(0, index); //cuts up line and assigns to locateWord
while (locateWord != "<VoltAmpereReactiveTimeSeries")
{
    getline(infile, s);
    index = s.find(' ');
    locateWord = s.substr(0, index);

}
    s = s.substr(index + 1, s.length());
    infile.ignore(116, '\n'); // Ignores all of the stuff on the "<VoltAmpereReactiveTimeSeries" line and gets to the numbers on the subsequent line

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int count = 0; count < 25; count++) //sums 25 voltage/wattage values
        {
            infile >> dataValues;//extract voltage data values from InFile
            sum += dataValues;
        }
        ave = sum / 25.0; //calculate the average voltage
        cout << "Average Voltage: " << ave  << endl;//outputs ave on screen
        outFile << "Average Voltage: " << ave << endl; //Prints the average to out file
        sum = 0; // re initialize sum 
        infile.ignore(176, '\n'); 

    }
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) { 
        for (int countb = 0; countb < 25; countb++) //sums 25 voltage/wattage values
        {
            infile >> dataValues;//extract wattage data values from infile
            sum += dataValues;
        }
        ave = sum / 25.0; //calculate the average wattage
        cout << "Average Wattage: " << ave << endl;//outputs ave on screen
        outFile << "Average Wattage: " << ave << endl; //Prints the average to out file
        sum = 0; // re initialize sum 
        infile.ignore(176, '\n');

    }
}
```

Comment: `while (!infile.eof())`  Already we have an issue:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong  Also, why not use an XML parser instead of trying to do this yourself?

Comment: Don't do `while (!infile.eof())`, it will not work as you expect. Instead do e.g. `while (std::getline(...))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that once the `timestamps` function returns, the file is at the end, so when the `voltAvg` function tries to read from the file it's already at the end. You need to "rewind" the file between the calls by using the [`seekg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) function.

This would be very evident if you actually checked the stream status, by doing e.g. `while (getline(...))` instead in the `voldAvg` function.

Comment: Thank you, `seekg` wasn't in my knowledge-bank. However, it is now! Thanks!

Comment: Actually, if it's not too much of a bother there is one minor hiccup left. While my program is now actually outputting 6 averages for each of the 6 lines as I intended it to, I am not obtaining the averages I want. E.G: http://imgur.com/kabVeX8     Here's my code currently: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/acfe6633f8b8d56ec2e2